# Pear Excel Writer ENCODING

Tags: excel, encoding, pear, writer

I'm developing an automated Excel-Export with Pear Excel Writer:
http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/docs

I used $worksheet->setInputEncoding("ISO-8859-1") to set the encoding, because my PHP system gives back ISO-8859-1 if i use iconv();

But in the Excel file I have display errors with umlaut (in german).

---

***** PHP *****

```
require_once 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php';

$workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();
$workbook->send('data.xls');

$worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet('Data');
$worksheet->setInputEncoding("ISO-8859-1"); // !?!?!

// some $worksheet->write() and so on

$worksheet->write($row, 2, 'Priotität', $format_bold); // The problem is the word with 'ä'
```

***** PROBLEM *****

it looks like this in the excel sheet:

http://www.pic-upload.de/view-25183541/Unbenannt.png.html

Comment: please provide some example code that gives the result you describe.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm now having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code is written in UTF-8, but you set the input encoding to iso-8859-1.

Set the input encoding to utf-8 to fix the issue.